# Difference between the estimated coefficients within the model

Tags: regression

I tried to understand the methodology used in literature(Abbot and Beach 1994) but I couldn't find how to make the result.

If you look at Table 4 in the paper, there are 3 columns, b1hat, b2hat and b1hat - b2hat. I can get b1hat and b2hat with the regression model but I don't know how to get b1hat - b2hat.